# Is there a book on gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I am working on a turtlebot with gazebo. However, I am looking for more documentation on gazebo with ros using turtlebots as the ground robots. So far, I have not gotten far to find good book on it. Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14323/is-there-a-book-on-gazebo?/) by [Vinh K](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2792/vinh-k/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2016-09-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

as far as I know, no such book exists. They will be mentions of gazebo in various ROS books, but no book solely on gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2016-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2792/vinh-k/) on 2016-09-02**:
I see. What is the best way to learn Gazebo so one can incorporate it with ROS?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-09-02**:
I think the best way to learn about Gazebo is following the tutorials, they're constantly updated.
http://gazebosim.org/tutorials

**Comment by [shpower](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/928/shpower/) on 2016-09-04**:
In addition to tutorials there are two good books: 'ROS BY EXAMPLE' vol.2 (vol.1 is good for turtlebot, but without gazebo) and 'Mastering ROS for Robotics  Programming'

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

To complement the answer above books and chapters which contain content about gazebo:

**ROS Robotics by Example** 1st edition

- Chapter 2, Creating Your First Two-Wheeled ROS Robot (in Simulation)
- Chapter 3. Driving Around with TurtleBot
- Chapter 5. Creating Your First Robot Arm (in Simulation)
- Chapter 6. Wobbling Robot Arms Using Joint Control
- Chapter 7. Making a Robot Fly

**Learning Robotics using Python** 1st edition

- Chapter 3: Working with Robot Simulation Using ROS and Gazebo

**Learning ROS for Robotics Programming** 2nd edition

- Chapter 7. 3D Modeling and Simulation
- Chapter 8. The Navigation Stack - Robot Setups
- Chapter 10. Manipulation with MoveIt!

**Mastering ROS for Robotics Programming** 1st edition

- Chapter 3. Simulating Robots Using ROS and Gazebo
- Chapter 4. Using the ROS MoveIt! and Navigation Stack
- Chapter 5. Working with Pluginlib, Nodelets, and Gazebo Plugins
- Chapter 10. Exploring the Advanced Capabilities of ROS-MoveIt!

**Programming Robots with ROS: A Practical Introduction to the Robot Operating System** 1st edition

- Chapter 6: Robots and Simulators
- Chapter 7: Wander-bot
- Chapter 8: Teleop-bot
- Chapter 11: Chess-bot
- Chapter 12: Follow-bot
- Chapter 14: Stockroom-bot
- Chapter 16: Your Own Mobile Robot
- Chapter 18: Your Own Robot Arm

---

Originally posted by [thinwybk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4165/thinwybk/) with karma: 31 on 2017-11-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3